# Regex to find instance of word in any circumstance within a line

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to find a word in any circumstance where it would appear in a line.

I would need to find Apple (case insensitive) in:

```
to much applesauce
   apple_computers
*applesdf
```

or any other way that I may come across the word apple.

What I have so far:

```
(?i)^.*?(apple).*?
```

Update: I'm trying to accomplish this in Python pandas where rows for a particular column would contain the word apple anywhere within the row for only that column

If I had this data frame:

```
   A     B       C  D      E    F
0  1 no apple    1  3   test  foo
1  1 retrain     1  3  train  foo
2  1 applesfas   1  3   test  foo
3  1 fit         1  3  train  foo
```

I would get back something like this:

```
   A     B       C  D      E    F
0  1 no apple    1  3   test  foo
2  1 applesfas   1  3   test  foo
```

For the filtering I know I would use something like this:

```
appleFilter = data['B'].str.contains('\bApple\b')
```

Comment: which language or command are you using?

Comment: Isn't this trivial? `re.findall('apple', your_variable, re.IGNORECASE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) has a case flag, to be case insensitive:

```
In [11]: df["B"].str.contains("apple", case=False)
Out[11]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: B, dtype: bool

In [12]: df[df["B"].str.contains("apple", case=False)]
Out[12]:
   A          B  C  D     E    F
0  1   no apple  1  3  test  foo
2  1  applesfas  1  3  test  foo
```